# Adjective that describes the pattern in wood from insects boring tunnels along the surface beneath the bark?

Tags: single-word-requests

I once read a word that described the pattern seen below. What might that word be? I'm quite certain it ended in "-iculated".

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**vermiculated**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/vermiculate#)

> 1. Bearing wavy, wormlike lines.
> 2. Having a wormlike motion; twisting or wriggling.
> 3. Infested with worms; worm-eaten.

Comment: Fish in a barrel, really. But people keep moaning if I post something like that in a comment. Anyway, it just so happens I really like this word, and your pic is great. (I like  *vermicelli* and *vermiculite* too, but not in the same way! :)

Comment: Wow I never spotted the similarity! Of course *verme* is Italian for worm! Go figure. Thanks for the mini-lesson. And yes, me too, such a cool word. Sounds cool and represents something beautiful and unusual.

Comment: I quite like ***formica*** too, but apparently the origin of that one is uncertain. I kinda doubt it's got anything to do with *ants* though!